# How to display check-boxes horizontally in this code base

Tags: php, html

We have an autogen form in php, the way we spit out the checkbox is shown in the code below:

```
case FIELD_CHECK_BOX:
                $fieldHtml = printCheckbox($mode, $field->getId().'[]', $field->getOptions(), $field->getValue(), true, '&nbsp;&nbsp', $isReq, array( "class"=>$isReq,$jsFunctionCalls));
            break;
```

the issue is, if you have five checkboxes for example, they print vertically, but I have a client that has a ton of checkboxes and wants them to print horizontally.

How can I code this to spit the checkboxes out next to each other until say five boxes have been reached and then break to the next line .

**HTML Output:**

```
<tr class="tr-11-16 tr-11" id="field-16"><td width='30%' valign='top' align='left' class='labeltext'>Requestor Email :<span style='text-decoration:none' class='required' id='lfspan'> * </span></td><td width='70%' align='left'><table border='0' style='table-layout:auto'><tr><td><div id='td-16[]'><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td class="valuetext fld-3-16-required" ><input type="checkbox" name="16[]" id="16[]" value="Home"class="valuetext fld-3-16-required" 0="">Home</td></tr><tr><td class="valuetext fld-3-16-required" ><input type="checkbox" name="16[]" id="16[]" value="Play"class="valuetext fld-3-16-required" 0="">Play</td></tr><tr><td class="valuetext fld-3-16-required" ><input type="checkbox" name="16[]" id="16[]" value="Theatre"class="valuetext fld-3-16-required" 0="">Theatre</td></tr><tr><td class="valuetext fld-3-16-required" ><input type="checkbox" name="16[]" id="16[]" value="Work"class="valuetext fld-3-16-required" 0="">Work</td></tr></table></div></td><td valign='top'></td></tr></table></td></tr>
```

Comment: What HTML is produced from `printCheckbox()`?

Comment: You should do that in css.

Comment: We need to know the return value of `printCheckbox()`. As a blind shot, you can set `display:inline` for FORM element. Anyway, your vertical display is caused by `block` element.

Comment: Ben I added the html output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is tables.

Better way is to use `display:table` and its blocks.

Best way would probably be to wrap each checkbox + label in a wrapper element, and give that element 20% width. Then each of those wrapper elements can have either `display:inline-block;` or `display:block; float:left;`

Comment: Humm,  can't use tables in this code base, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using Firebug, `tr { display:inline }` allows the checkboxes to flow as if they were just input elements in a row.

What would be fantastic, is if your function would output `<input><input><input>`, rather than a a nested `<table>`